# Simplifying $(-2x^2 y^{-1} )^3 / 2y^{-2}$, with positive exponents

Tags: exponentiation, real-numbers

The question is 
$$(-2x^2 y^{-1} )^3 / 2y^{-2} $$

I did it till 
$$-4x^6 y^{-1}$$
I'm told to put it in a form of positive indices .
Can I say that the answer is
$x^6 / 4y$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Close, but do it as

$$-4x^6 / y.$$

You can't get rid of the minus in front of 4, but this is alright, as you only want the exponents to be positive.

Comment: Alright ! Thanks a lot !